# Bind list of object to datagridview in VB

Tags: vb.net, list, datagridview

I want to bind a list of objects to a DataGridView in VB.

It worked first with using datagrid.Rows.Add(...) for each result, but that blocks the program.
I've read it could be solved by binding a list of objects to the DataGridView with .DataSource.
But it don't work, my datagridview remains empty...

What is wrong? Is it something in the GUI-code (see below)?

This where the logic happens:

```
Public queryList As New List(Of _study)

...

If _objResponse.Status = CurrentStatus.Pending Then
        Dim _newStudy As New _study

        ' Parse one study from the response (_objResponse.Dataset.[Get](Of String)(DicomTag.StudyDate))
        _newStudy._studyID = _objResponse.Dataset.[Get](Of String)(DicomTag.StudyInstanceUID)
        _newStudy._name =  _objResponse.Dataset.[Get](Of String)(DicomTag.AccessionNumber)

        ' Save study info for later use
        queryList.Add(_newStudy)            

ElseIf _objResponse.Status = DicomStatus.Success
        dgvResults.DataSource = queryList
        ...
Else
        MsgBox("Failed")
End If
```

Here is the _newStudy class:

```
Public Class _study

   Private _studyID As String
   Private _name As String

   Public Property _studyID() As String
     Get
        Return _studyID
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As String)
        _studyID = value
      End Set
   End Property

   Public Property _name() As String
     Get
        Return _name
     End Get
     Set(ByVal value As String)
        _name = value
     End Set
   End Property
End Class
```

And here is the code of the DataGridView() GUI:

```
Private colName As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Private colID As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Private dgvResults As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

...

Me.dgvResults = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
Me.colID = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
Me.colName = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()

Me.dgvResults.AllowUserToAddRows = false
Me.dgvResults.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false
Me.dgvResults.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
Me.dgvResults.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
Me.dgvResults.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn() {Me.colID, Me.colName})
Me.dgvResults.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 19)
Me.dgvResults.Name = "dgvResults"
Me.dgvResults.ReadOnly = true
Me.dgvResults.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(540, 206)
Me.dgvResults.TabIndex = 2

'colID
Me.colID.HeaderText = "Study ID"
Me.colID.DataPropertyName = "_studyID"
Me.colID.Name = "colID"
Me.colID.ReadOnly = true

'colPatientName
Me.colName.HeaderText = "Name"
Me.colName.DataPropertyName = "_name"
Me.colName.Name = "_name"
Me.colName.ReadOnly = true

...

CType(Me.dgvResults,System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit
```

I think the  DataPropertyName is correct to get the link between the objects and the datagrid, right...?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It isn't clear from your code *when* the DataGridView control has its DataSource set.  Is that happening all the time?  Only when your get Success status?  Only show us real code, btw, your _study class doesn't compile and you should avoid leading underscores on public properties and names.  You are adding the column Me.colPatientID twice to the grid in the designer?

Answer (score 1):

The List object doesn't transmit any information that the list has been updated or changed.

To do that, try using the BindingList from the System.ComponentModel namespace:

```
Public queryList As New BindingList(Of _study)
```

Comment: Good call, but still no data on the grid

Comment: @francisMi See my comment to your post.  The code posted doesn't make it very clear if everything is wired correctly or not.  I would think you would set the DataSource to the grid earlier in the process.